# pywinauto change default timeout values

Tags: pywinauto

I am using Timings.Defaults() in my pywinauto/python code. However, for certain operations like

```
app.window_(title_re = windowTitle).Wait('visible', timeout=1)
```

code waits for 5 seconds if the window is not visible. I have given timeout as 1 seconds but still it waits for 5 seconds. How do I change this 5 second wait to a shorter time?

Comment: Hmm... I've looked into the code and haven't seen any obvious errors. But I could reproduce it on simple example using Notepad. Thanks for the bug report! Hope to fix it in 0.6.3 planned in May.

Comment: Will track it as [issue 347](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/347).

Comment: Would you recommend any fix that I can add locally to the core pywinauto library on my machine or change the value if it is part of any configuration file?

Comment: Need to debug it. Will let you know when I have a fix.

Comment: When I use `wait('exists', timeout=1)` it fits in ~1 sec. So it's specific for `'visible'` state.

Comment: You can try [this branch](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto/tree/thunder-rt6). Should be fixed, but I need to write unit tests before merging to upstream.

Comment: Thank You. Will pull that branch.

Comment: Now the changes are in master with some more fixes and auto-tested. Will publish 0.6.3 till end of May.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Will let you know incase of issues.

Comment: How about accepting the answer about the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug with timings is fixed in pywinauto 0.6.3. Please update it with `pip install -U pywinauto`.