# Pywinauto taking long time for operations

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, pywinauto

I'm having troubles with automating filtering in a certain window of a program, that i'm working on. A window consists of listview, few comboboxes and few edits. When i select certain position in the combobox2 and click "filter", then listview shows results matching with that checkbox.
  But here i have problem. After clicking filter manually, program loads results for a short time (~2 seconds), but if i do it with pywinauto, then it takes up to ~10 seconds before it moves to another function which should select another position in the combobox. (even then i can click it manualy and it works fine, so it's 100% not problem with the program)

Here's example of a code which causes troubles.

```
user_count = 0
while user_count < 5:
    self.app[kkvat].ComboBox2.Select(user_count)
    self.app[kkvat].Filter.Click()
    user_count += 1
```

The problems shows up exactly at the second loop when the 2 position of combobox should be selected.

Sorry for my language, not native :(

Comment: It might be connected with [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43558087/3648361). Can you try with [this branch](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto/tree/thunder-rt6)?

Comment: We made some optimizations and merged them into master branch. Can you try to update from master and re-check the same scenario? Is there some improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug with timings is fixed in pywinauto 0.6.3. Please update it with `pip install -U pywinauto` and try your case again.

Comment: Thank you, it helped somehow

Comment: Great. If it resolves the problem, please mark this answer as accepted. It's considered polite on SO. Just click on grayed check box under voting buttons (it must always work for an author of question).